# How mmap with NULL addr works?

Tags: c, memory, null, mmap

It is specified that when using `mmap` with `NULL` *addr*, the kernel chooses the (page-aligned) address at which to create the mapping:

> mmap() creates a new mapping in the virtual address space of the
>          calling process.  The starting address for the new mapping is
>          specified in addr.  The length argument specifies the length of the
>          mapping (which must be greater than 0). **If addr is NULL, then the kernel chooses the (page-aligned) address
>          at which to create the mapping**; this is the most portable method of
>          creating a new mapping.

Supposing I have the code below :

```
void (*x)(void);
void (*y)(void);
x=mmap(NULL, 0x500, PROT..., FLAGS..., FD..., 0);
y=mmap(NULL, 0x500, PROT..., FLAGS..., FD..., 0);
```

Does it means that `y` will follow just after `x` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Where in the text you quote does it talk about such guarantee?

Comment: It says the kernel gets to do the choosing. That should make it fairly clear you should not be making any assumptions about its choice.

Comment: Why are you assigning the returned memory to a function pointer?  What do you intend to do with it?

Comment: [man mmap](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) says `If addr is not NULL, then the kernel takes it as a hint about where to place the mapping; on Linux, the mapping will be created at a nearby page boundary. The address of the new mapping is returned as the result of the call.` Which part is unclear?

Comment: The actual question is: Why would you care? This is clearly an XY problem.

Comment: Sorry guys, I just misunderstood the man of mmap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not say anything about the relative positioning of the mappings so you can't make any assumptions about it. Treat each mapping as completely separate from all others.

Comment: Thanks. even if I made assumption because of a misunderstanding of the mmap man page, the question is still relevant I think, as well as the answer of course.